# POCO: Concurrent access to SecureStreamSocket

Tags: c++, openssl, poco-libraries

I have 2 concurrent threads: one for writing, another for reading from SecureStreamSocket. But OpenSSL docs says that calling SSL_read and SSL_write concurrently is wrong. Our application protocol is full duplex. How can I use TLS/SSL POCO classes for full duplex protocol?

Answer (score 0):

You can have one single thread that does the socket I/O, and all other threads communicates with this I/O thread.

Comment: I have one thread with socket, but others use it in parallel. I can't lock underlying read and write socket operations with mutexes. I need read client requests when write processing.

Comment: @cybergnom You can use a message queue system, where the other threads send messages to the I/O thread, the I/O thread uses those messages to know what to send/receive through the socket, and then the I/O thread replies to the messages to the originating thread. This means that only a single thread uses the socket.